# Snoring noises at night in the summer?

Tags: animal-behaviour, europe, night

When I slept outside in central Europe, I often recognized extremely loud snoring noises. It's not really rattling but more like rhythmical breathing. I heard it as a kid for the first time and I remember that it scared the hell out of me :)

What animal can cause such noises?

Worth to mention: a mate once told me that hedgehogs can sleep very loudly. However, as I've researched a little bit, it doesn't seem to be true (but can't really figure out a definite answer).

Comment: Hedgehogs are nocturnal so they won't be asleep at night!

Comment: @Liam Hmmm good to know because actually it can be the noises of hedgehog-sexy-time :) http://www.onekind.org/education/animals_a_z/hedgehog

Comment: Humans. The sound is humans.

Comment: If you were near Yellowstone, it would be a bison. They'll lay ten feet away from your tent making that phlegmy sound all d*** night. But that's probably better than being eaten by a grizzly. In Europe it's probably a cow.

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced similar noises at night. I'm guessing what you're hearing are deer. Deer around the world make a wide variety of noises.  I'm in N. America and the deer in my area make a loud snorting sound at night, especially if you set up on or near one of their game trails. Here's a link to a video where you can hear a lot of different examples. https://youtu.be/UO6FvalHULo